# Cant connect to the Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms-2014

For the past month I have been using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio tool to connect to my database which created on the Azure portal. Recently I received updates from Microsoft related to Microsoft Visual Studio. After I installed these, I can't connect to my SQL database (previously it was working fine). [Update History Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqvWQ.png) I attached the screenshot of recent updates (which I installed) and the error message for your view.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVEQL.png)
Please help to solve this issue.

note: I am an SQL beginner, so I don't know many technical things related to tools, so please keep your answers to my level, Thanks!

> Update: Error Message 
>   TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> ---
>
> Cannot connect to abcxyz.database.windows.net.
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

The network path was not found

Comment: Did your IP address change by chance?  Azure has firewall restrictions to connect to sql I believe -- you have to go to the portal and add the allowed IP addresses.  Just a guess...

Comment: Can you paste error message instead of screenshot ?

Comment: @sgeddes : nope. my ip not changed. I added my ip address to the firewall settings already in azure.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I can't embed the image directly since I registered today only(Stackoverflow told)..lol

Comment: paste the error text,some users might have images blocked in domain

Comment: @TheGameiswar error text pasted..

Comment: try adding 1433 at end

Comment: abcxyz.database.windows.net,1433

Comment: getting this error now.  TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to abcxyz.database.windows.net,1433.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=258&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The wait operation timed out

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you tried to create a connection to an endpoint and you were expecting a acknowledgment from sql server, however, that acknowledgement did not occur. This means that you are either blocked by your own network, a  network in route, or the endpoint network (which all three could be your own if, running locally). I would start by pinging that server ip address and seeing what you come up with.

Comment: How can I find whether I blocked or not? and I am not getting the last point.

Answer (score 0):

that problem solved automatically, when I tried to keep connecting. really I don't know what was the problem..thanks for ur reply guys.

Comment: This is not an answer and it doesnt help any one,please try to update question based on this info